# add key-value to array in javascript without loop

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need some way to add key-value in array without use a loop.

```
const arrayA = [{name: "luis"}, {name: "carla"}, {name: "maria"}];

for (let i = 0; i < arrayA.length; i++) {
  const element = arrayA[i];
  element.selected = false;
}
```

I don't want to use a loop to add key `selected`.do some way exist to do it?. some node_module?

Comment: It's not possible, unless you hard-code each index. Every possible solution will require a loop of some sort.

Comment: `arrayA.forEach(o => o.selected=false)` - still a loop, technically, but not a *for loop*

Comment: As @CertainPerformance says, there will always be some kind of loop (maybe just behind the scenes as mentioned be @JaromandaX ) when doing something to all elements of an array in memory. If you have the initialization code as shown in your example, you could add the attribute there. E.g. `const arrayA = [{name: "luis", selected: false}, ...`

Comment: @abondoa - or to reduce repetition ... `const arrayA = [{name: "luis"}, {name: "carla"}, {name: "maria"}].map(o => ({...o, selected:false});`

Comment: or you could simply rely on the fact that if an object doesn't have `selected` property, then `o.selected` is undefined ... which is falsey

Comment: @JaromandaX, true, but there would be a loop inside the `map`, which OP does not want (as far as I understand).

Comment: @abondoa - yeah ... noobs usually don't consider "map" or "forEach" the same as a for loop, since he asked for a "node_module" in the question, I think it's safe to use such iterative methods

Comment: @JaromandaX and user120242 Yeah, maybe you guys are right. OP can you elaborate on why you don't want to use a loop?

Comment: whether you need to loop explicitly or use can some services live map which does loop implicitly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ideas of a loop and of visiting every item in an array are fundamentally tied. There a are a few ways to hide a loop, like forEach or map....

```js
let arrayA = [{name: "luis"}, {name: "carla"}, {name: "maria"}];
arrayA = arrayA.map(e => ({ selected: true, ...e}))

console.log(arrayA)
```

Comment: @JaromandaX seems immaterial, but okay

Comment: Map is still a loop. It loops through each item and creates a copy of each item

Comment: @MosiaThabo, is my answer not clear enough that map is also a loop?

Answer (score 2):

*(I was debating myself whether I should post this, but it's educational and answers the question)*

This works by modifying the prototype for the base `Object` type so that the property `selected` is inherited by all objects.  Also note that this will modify all objects to have a selected property.

```js
const arrayA = [{name: "luis"}, {name: "carla"}, {name: "maria"}];
Object.prototype.selected = false;
console.log( arrayA );
```

Please do not use that in any real code.  Meant for illustrative purposes.  It is not a good way to achieve what you are looking for.
Below makes use of the prototype chain:

```js
function X(o) { return Object.create(X.prototype, Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(o)); }
const arrayA = [X({name: "luis"}), X({name: "carla"}), X({name: "maria"})];
X.prototype.selected = false;
console.log( arrayA );
```

Above snippet has real uses and implications, and you will find similar code in advanced uses in some libraries.  But this is most likely not useful in the context of OP's intentions.  It is akin to abusing `eval` for assigning variables or building loops.

Comment: At least do something like `function X(o) { return Object.create(X.prototype, Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(o)); }` so that it doesn't rely on the deprecated `__proto__` property.

Answer (score 1):

Even any 3 party lib also loop it. You can simplify using `Object.assign` and `map`.

```js
const modify = (arr) => arr.map((x) => Object.assign(x, { selected: false }));

const arrayA = [{ name: "luis" }, { name: "carla" }, { name: "maria" }];
console.log(modify(arrayA));
```